# Add Like restriction to dictionary

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I set an nHibernate restriction for a project Id like so:

```
var attachmentProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>();
attachmentProperties.Add("Id", this.project.Id);
```

so it returns anything with that project Id by setting the Restrictions:

```
NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.AllEq(attachmentProperties));
```

This works. I now want to add another restriction using the equivalent of a SQL Like. I tried:

```
attachmentProperties.Add(NHibernate.Criterion.Restrictions.Like("Type", "%dog%"));
```

> There is no argument given that corresponds to required formal
>   parameter value

I want to get anything in which the Type contains "dog" (in addition to the Id matching). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Have all the Dog classes implement a common interface (IDog).  Then, the dictionary will be:

```
new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, IDog>();
```

or, you could do this, which might be a little strange, if what's up top isn't available for some reason where you validate the Add method.  You'd similarly have to have checks on other methods.

```
    class DogDictionary : Dictionary<string, object>
    {

        public virtual void Add(KeyValuePair<string, object> item)
        {

            if (item.Value.GetType().ToString().ToUpper().Contains("DOG"))
                throw new ApplicationException("Invalid Data Type for Value.  Should Have 'Dog' in the Object Name");
        }
    }
```

I'd go with the first option though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create a `Restrictions.Conjunction` for the Criteria:

```
Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.Conjunction();
conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", this.project.Id));
conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Like("Type", "%dog%"));
conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Not(Restrictions.Like("Type", "%cat%")));
```